# Postgres - Trigger with matched key

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have several tables.  A table, cexp, is a table that has attributes cid and total.  Cid is grouped and total is the sum of quantity * price for that cid (matched on cid)

The cexp table was populated with the results of the following code:

```
SELECT c.cid, sum(ol.quantity*b.price) as total
FROM customers c join orders o on c.cid=o.cid
                       join orderlist ol on o.ordernum=ol.ordernum
                       join books b on b.isbn=ol.isbn
GROUP BY C.CID
```

My task is to create a trigger that, when inserting rows for order and orderderlist, finds the matching name, in cexp and increments the existing total by the product of new quantity (from orderlist) and the price (from books).  If no match, insert a row in cexp.

Tables are as follows:

Customers-cid,name   pk-cid

Books - isbn,title,price   pk-isbn

Orders - ordernum,cid   pk-ordernum

Orderlist - ordernum,isbn, quantity  - pk-(ordernum,isbn)

cexp - cid,total   - pk-cid

I am getting syntax errors.  Can anyone correct this code?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cexpupd()
RETURNS trigger as 
$cexpupd$
BEGIN
UPDATE cexp
SET new.total=total+Select (b.price*new.quantity) FROM customers c
 join orders o on c.cid=o.cid
 join orderlist ol on o.ordernum=ol.ordernum
 join books b on b.isbn=ol.isbn
 where b.isbn=new.isbn;
 --INSERT CODE WHEN ABOVE LINE DOES NOT OCCUR -INSERTS NEW ROW INTO CEXP
 END;
 $cexpupd$ 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: Exactly what does the error message say?

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Select"
     LINE 7: SET new.total=total+Select (b.price*new.quantity) FROM 
                            ^
     ********** Error **********

     ERROR: syntax error at or near "Select"
     SQL state: 42601
     Character: 130

Comment: I have an idea. Can you post your `CREATE TRIGGER` statement so I can be sure which tables I'm dealing with?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER cexpupd
    BEFORE INSERT on barosb01_orderlist
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE cexpupd();

Thanks for the follow-up!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that your **UPDATE** statement is an unsalvageable birds-nest. Fortunately, there's an easier way to achieve the same result.

Keep in mind that a trigger function is *procedural* code, so there's no need to [concurrently load the gun, pull the trigger, scream, and shoot yourself in the foot](http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Humor/Docs/ShootYourselfInTheFoot.html) in a single statement. You have access to all the procedural goodies like local variables and flow control statements.

The following should give you a good headstart on what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cexpupd()
  RETURNS trigger as 
  $cexpupd$
    DECLARE
      bookprice     books.price%TYPE;
      ext_total     cexp.total%TYPE;
      custid        orders.cid%TYPE;

    BEGIN
      SELECT cid
        INTO custid
        FROM orders
        WHERE orders.ordernum = NEW.ordernum;

      SELECT price
        INTO bookprice
        FROM books
        WHERE books.isbn = NEW.isbn;

      ext_total = bookprice * NEW.quantity;

      UPDATE cexp
        SET total = ext_total
        WHERE cid = custid;
      IF NOT FOUND THEN
        --INSERT new CID record here
        INSERT INTO cexp
            (cid, total)
          VALUES
            (custid, ext_total);
      END IF;

      RETURN NEW;
    END;
  $cexpupd$ 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note the statement near the end, `RETURN NEW;` This line is crucial, as it is how a PostgreSQL trigger function tells the database to go ahead and finish executing the statement that fired the trigger.

If you need any clarification, please don't hesitate to ask. Please note I have not tried executing this function, but I did create the necessary tables to compile it successfully.